# Rich Snippets Questions

Tags: google-search-console

I am introducing rich snippets on my site and have some questions I can't find solution:

- Do I need to put main company snippet only on mainpage or all pages (contacts, social networks, etc) -  I mean copy the code on all links?
- How do I do the beauty two columns snippets with the main site links, and how do I define what these main links are? - Example when we search Facebook we see: Facebook Login, Facebook Register, Facebook Profile, etc... all with a brief description below. Are there the separate pages that contain snippet and google identifies the most relevant? What code to put on each page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to add knowledge graph items you just need to markup your homepage only. For individual rich snippet items like star ratings, breadcrumbs etc you'll have to mark each page for them to show up for all of your search results.

Contact and Social profiles as you mentioned are knowledge graph items.

In the second part I am assuming you are referring to the links below the branded search result. The are not [rich snippets](http://www.mywebandseo.com/rich-snippets-and-structured-data-for-advanced-seo/) but are rather called [sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) and are generated if you have good on-site structure and internal linking. Sitelinks are picked by Google itself and you have little control over them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sitelink info!
I was looking in every corner of the internet how to get these "rich snippets" and you learnt me that these are called sitelinks and that we do not have that much control on it!
Big thanks!